# How to pass multiple instances of models to controller in form

Tags: asp.net

I'm setting up an asp.net form which collects reading from 5 power generators.

This is the model for each generator

```
 public class GeneratorModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public float Belasting { get; set; }
    public float MaxBelasting { get; set; }
    public float KoudeReserve { get; set; }
}
```

This is my view currently

```
@model XX.Models.GeneratorModel
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Data Entry";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "DataEntry", FormMethod.Post))
{
<table>
    <tr>Generator 1</tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Enter Belasting: </td>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Belasting)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Enter Max Belasting: </td>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MaxBelasting)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Koude Reserve: </td>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.KoudeReserve)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Submit Form" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
}
```

and my Controller is

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(GeneratorModel generatorModel)
{
   return Content("Hello");
}
```

Currently I can only enter values of 1 generator, but I need to take reading from 5 generators.

Is there a way that I can get an Array of GeneratorModel object as parameter in controller action result?

Comment: what if you need to take reading of 6 generators tomorrow or 7 generators? will you keep on adding input fields on the same page for every new generator? Ideally you should have a page with all the generators in a table and each table row should have edit and delete buttons. On top of the table there should be a create button which will redirect you to a new generator form from where you can create a new generator

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this:

```
    <table class="col-md-offset-2 table table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
               <th>Name</th>
               <th>Belasting</th>
               <th>Max Belasting</th>                        
               <th>Koude Reserve</th>
               <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="GenaratorList">
            <tr>
               <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)</td>
               <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Belasting)</td>
               <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MaxBelasting)</td>
               <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.KoudeReserve)</td>                        
               <td><input type="button" value="Add" onclick="addGenarator()"/></td>
            </tr>        
         </tbody>        
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit Form" />
```

Then add some javascript to append new rows each time you click add and click submit only after you have added required no. of rows of genrator.
Change your controller to this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(List<GeneratorModel> generatorModels)
{
   return Content("Hello");
}
```

And the JS for appending new table rows:

```
<script>
count=0;
function addGenarator() {
    var name = $('#Manifest_Quantity').val();
    var belasting= $('#Belasting').val();
    var mxBelasting= $('#MaxBelasting').val()
    var reserve= $('#KoudeReserve').val();

    var generator= "generatorModels[" + count + "]";
            $('#GenaratorList').append('<tr><td><input id="' + generator + '.Name" name="' + generator + '.Name" type="text" class="form-control" readonly value="' + name + '"></td><td><input id="' + generator + '.Belasting" name="' + generator + '.Belasting" type="text" class="form-control" readonly value="' + belasting + '"></td><td><input id="' + generator + '.MaxBelasting" name="' + generator + '.MaxBelasting" type="text" class="form-control" readonly value="' + mxBelasting + '"></td><td><input id="' + generator + '.KoudeReserve" name="' + generator + '.KoudeReserve" type="text" class="form-control" readonly value="' + reserve + '"></td></tr>');
            $('#Name,#Belasting,#MaxBelasting,#KoudeReserve').val('');    
            count++;    
        }    
</script>
```